# Repeat a task on all datasets available in Global Enviroment at once

Tags: r

I have about 40 datasets or more loaded in my Global enviroment. Each Dataset has two columns and 5 observation they all look the same. I want to rename the second field name from Filter to Pieces_Mailed then replace the 1st observation in the now Pieces_Mailed field with the value in the 5th observation because this is dynamic in all datasets. Afterwards, i want to retain only the two columns (Institution and Pieces_Mailed) with the the 1st observation.

Please, use the code below to create the dataset. County is just one of the 40+ dataset i have loaded. Everything is pretty much the same in these datasets except obs 1 in col 1 which has the institution name, col 2, obs 5 in the inital data.

I would prefer to use Tidyverse approach.

```
County <- tibble(Institution = c("Zoe Financials","NA","Mailing Summary", "Total Households & Members", 37867),
                 Filter = c("None", "NA", "Mailing Summary", "Pieces Mailed", 59475))

County <- tibble(Institution = "Zoe Financials",
                 Filter = 59475)
```

Comment: Is it better to write these datasets into one excel file before making the changes i want or just perform the task while the datasets are loaded into R? Please, let me know and Thanks for your time.

Comment: How are the objects named in the global env

Comment: They are name as Dane, Capital, Chase etc. All different names.

Comment: Are these the only objects in the global env  If these are different names

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to load the datasets into a `list` and then loop through the `list` with `lapply` from `base R` (or `map` from `purrr` - tidyverse), `select` the columns of interest (within  `select` we can also rename the columns if needed), then, `replace` the first values in 'Pieces_Mailed' with the fifth value of that column and return the datasets in a `list`.  It is better to keep the datasets in a `list` and not to assign or create multiple objects in the global environment as 1) it would clutter the enviornment, 2) It is easier to do any other modifications/saving as file from a `list` than from objects scattered in the global env

```
library(tidyverse)
lst1 <- mget(ls())
lst1 <- map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
                select(Institution,  Pieces_Mailed = Filter) %>%                   
                mutate(Pieces_Mailed = replace(Pieces_Mailed, 1,  Pieces_Mailed[5])) %>%
               slice(1))
```

Comment: @Omomaxi  Hmm, I thought you would assign `lst1 <- map(lst1, ..`

Comment: Thanks @ akrun I don't think this solved my problems. The list is only a merge of all the datasets in the Global Env named as Ist1 no changes. The two columns with 1 obseervation wasn't created in them. What i plan to do is merge the col from Dane back to another Dane dataset which contains 11 cols in it and this would be repeated wor the other datasets  such as Capital, Chase etc. I just need to have these fields as is in the each of the datasets in the console.

Comment: @Omomaxi  The merge part is not part of your question.  It is described as changing the column names and replacing the first value of the column with the 5th value

Comment: I can't help but think that it might be better to write all these objects into a single excel file before performing the task i want. So that way it loops through each of those excel files. I don't know...

Comment: @ akrun. the second column should be changed from Filter to Pieces_Mailed, secondly, the 1st observation in the 2nd column which is now None should be replaced with the 5th observation then thirdly, row 2:5 should be deleted. This leaves each of the datasets with two column names (Institution and Pieces_Mailed) and one observation in each cols.

Comment: @Omomaxi If you check my code, it is replacing the column from 'Filter to "Pieces_Mailed, 2) replace the 1s observation in second column i.e. Pieces_Mailed  with the 5th observation, and then deleted the rows 2 to 5 with `slice` (updated

Comment: Thanks for your solution but It didn't work for me because when i call lst1 as an object, it doesn't have the changes made so i can't accept the solution.

Comment: @Omomaxi  I did showed how to make the changes by `<-`  It works for me

Comment: if it is a change that needs to be made on your code that i'm missing, please go ahead and make the change so i can see it otherwise i have used what you posted as a solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Omomaxi  I addressed the 3 things that you mentioned 1) rename the column, 2) replace the value in 5th row, 3) delete the rows, and assign it to a object.  I don't know what more you want

Comment: what i want is when i call the object lst1 i want to see the tibbles under with the changes. I am not seein it that way, what i'm seeing is just the combination of the same initial datasets assigned to an object lst1. Hence, there is no way to call the data in the list. each of them still has a dimension of 5 *2  instead of 1 *2

Comment: @Omomaxi  When I do `lst1 <- map(lst1, ~ .x %>%
                select(Institution,  Pieces_Mailed = Filter) %>%                   
                mutate(Pieces_Mailed = replace(Pieces_Mailed, 1,  Pieces_Mailed[5]) %>%
               slice(1))` it would update the  `lst1`  There must be some issue on your env

Comment: it's not updating. it looks like the code is missing a parenthesis somewhere. Please, confirm. I have tried to correct that but it's not working. I can see a + sign on the console when i run the second chunk.

Comment: @Omomaxi  Oh yes, you are right.  You should have mentioned this earlier.  I was thinking that it is not updating.  Corrected it.  It is in the `mutate` step

Comment: now it worked. Thanks. I will vote it up but what if i have more questions like the merge part of it to each of the main datasets, how do i approach this since it's a list and not objects? Would i need to open a new ticket for this? if yes, i'm not sure how to ask it. Please, let me know. Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: @Omomaxi  You can ask more question by posting new questions rather than having n number of questions from the same post